# Add elements into unequal list in python

Tags: python

I have two lists -:

```
a=[1,5,3,4,25,6]
```

and

```
b=[10,25,3]
```

Now I want this kind of output

```
b =[10,25,3,None,None,None]
```

To get this output , I used this

```
for x,y in itertools.zip_longest(a,b):
```

But, this doesn't help me. How do I get the desired ouput?

> after that I want give it size of a list , it doesn't matter whether we add Zero or None , at the end I want the size of both of those list is the same

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close. You can definitely use `zip_longest` to get to your desired output:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a = [1, 5, 3, 4, 25, 6]
b = [10, 25, 3]

[y for _, y in zip_longest(a, b)]
# [10, 25, 3, None, None, None]
```

A different option that does not unnecessarily produce the zipped pairs just to discard half of each would use an iterator and `next`:

```
it = iter(b)
[next(it, None) for _ in range(len(a))]
# [10, 25, 3, None, None, None]
```

Comment: Woah, Thanks Man!!

Comment: and what if we want to pass more than 2 list into this?  if I want to pass 4 list into this, and add None to each list which is shorter than our max_size of list, is it possible?

Comment: Well that'S a different question :) `zip_longest` can take more than 2 iterables. The other approach you would have to use the max length of all lists

Comment: got it, I added  one more concern to the question , please check and help it out

Comment: @NoobforSQL Pls state the exact input and the desired output data structure. I will be glad to specify my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just do

```
>>> b += [None]*(len(a) - len(b))                                                                                      
>>> b                                                                                                                  
[10, 25, 3, None, None, None]
```

> I want to pass 4 lists into this, and add `None` to each list which is shorter than the longest list, is it possible?

Building new lists (non-mutating):

```
>>> lists = [[1,5,3,4,25,6], [10,25,3], [], [1, 2]]                                                                    
>>> max_len = max(map(len, lists))                                                                                     
>>> [l + [None]*(max_len - len(l)) for l in lists]                                                                     
[[1, 5, 3, 4, 25, 6],
 [10, 25, 3, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [1, 2, None, None, None, None]]
```

With `itertools.zip_longest` (non-mutating):

```
>>> list(map(list, zip(*zip_longest(*lists))))                                                                         
[[1, 5, 3, 4, 25, 6],
 [10, 25, 3, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [1, 2, None, None, None, None]]
```

Mutating version:

```
>>> max_len = max(map(len, lists))                                                                                     
>>> for l in lists: 
...:     l.extend([None]*(max_len - len(l))) 
...:                                                                                                                   
>>> lists                                                                                                              
[[1, 5, 3, 4, 25, 6],
 [10, 25, 3, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [1, 2, None, None, None, None]]
```